# How to add a record with count of a column within one table using SQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, count, insert

I have an ASP.NET MVC application in which I have to copy the records of existing table `Material` once I click a button "Click Me".

The `Material` table has columns `ID, materialId, materialNumber` and so on. I added a new column called `New` in the `Material` table because every time I click "Click Me" button in an application, I should be able to add a new line with new Id and add record in (specific format described below) this new column.

The reason for this is I want to know which original `materialNumber` and `materialId` this new record is linked to.

Format of new record:

```
"It-Is-materialNumber(count of material id)-materialId"
```

For example:

```
"It-Is-5625(0)-159"
```

=> where It-Is"= regular words like "it is", 5625 = materialNumber and 159 = materialId.

Sample data:

```
ID | materialId | materialNumber | New               | 
---+------------+----------------+-------------------+
 1 | 159        |   5625         | It-Is-5625(0)-159 | 
 2 | 159        |   5625         | It-Is-5625(1)-159 | 
 3 | 159        |   5625         | It-Is-5625(2)-159 |
```

Initially count will be "0" and it keeps in increasing every time I click the "new" button as shown above.

`MaterialId` will be provided from my mvc code i.e. every time I click "Click Me", it will send original `materialId`. For simplicity, I have been hardcoding a materialId i.e. 159

My stored procedure is where I am confused and stuck right now. I am trying to create a stored procedure to insert new records into the newly added column in `Material` table:

```
select 
    *,
    (select COUNT(materialID) from Material where materialNumber = '5625') New
from 
    Material 
where 
    materialID = 159
```

I know only basic stored procedures that's why I am struggling much. I did research here on Stack Overflow, I found couple post but they are done in two different tables. So, can anyone help me out or direct me to some useful links?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.  The data in your table doesn't make a lot of sense.  How did you decide upon this format and why not put the parent ID just as an ID?  If you are trying to increment how often something occurs why not just put the count in the column?

Comment: Im trying to write a store procedure which will count the materialId and then add it in a new column in that specific format. Talking about format, it is what my assignment requirement is. Finally, incrementing count is not predefined. that count depends on the no of the click one click on the button "Click Me"

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.